# Hinten die Schenkel schlagend läuft man die langen Gassen hin. Was soll das?

Tags: meaning

In der Kurzerzählung "Der plötzliche Spaziergang" von F. Kafka stoße ich auf eine Wendung, die mich verwirrt:

> [...] während man selbst, ganz fest, schwarz vor Umrissenheit, hinten die Schenkel schlagend, sich zu seiner wahren Gestalt erhebt.

Da habe ich Missverständnis mit "hinten die Schenkel schlagend". Was soll das? Ist es im eigentlichen Sinne gebraucht? So hätte es wohl doof ausgesehen, wenn sich jemand beim Gang mit Händen auf die Schenkel klopft.
Oder ist es idiomatisch verwendet?
Dann entsteht die Frage, was für eine Bedeutung die Wendung beinhaltet?

Answer (score 5):

Aus dem Kontext würde ich sagen, dass es energisches Laufen beschreibt (beschreiben soll) – wenn man so wild läuft, dass die Unter- gegen die Oberschenkel *schlagen*.

Um jedoch herauszufinden, dass die Person gerade läuft und sich nur im übertragenen Sinne "erhebt", musste ich mir aber mehr von der [Erzählung](http://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/franz-kafka-erz-161/13) durchlesen.

Comment: Ich glaube auch, dass das ein laufender Jogger sein könnte.  Dies war jedenfalls mein erster Gedanke. Ich habe dann den ganzen Text gelesen, um sicher zu sein, dass hier von einem längeren Lauf die Rede ist.
https://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Der_pl%C3%B6tzliche_Spaziergang

Answer (score 1):

Aus dem Kontext der Erzählung kann ich das eigentlich nur als Abwandlung der Redewendung

> (vor Lachen/lachend) auf die Schenkel schlagen

verstehen, womit üblicherweise große Belustigung oder Freude ausgedrückt werden soll.

Das Schlagen der Schenkel "hinten" würde ich daher als Ausdruck  heimlicher/verborgener Freude oder Belustigung deuten.

Die Erzählung selbst lässt zusätzlich auch eine doppelte Deutung zu, in der das "hinten" zudem zielgerichtete Freude/Belustigung ausdrückt, nämlich in Richtung der Familie, bzw. der familiären Zwänge, welchen man sich gerade entzogen (abgewandt) hatte.

Answer (score 1):

Die hier zur Debatte gestellte Formulierung ist kafkaesk. Ganz bewusst vermeidet der Autor eine eindeutige Semantik und lässt Raum für Interpretationen.

Comment: Diese Frage verdeutlicht, dass es neben dem GERMAN LANGUAGE SE auch ein GERMAN LITERATURE SE geben müsste.

Answer (score 0):

Basierend auf dem kurzen Zitat, in dem die beschriebene Person sich gerade erhebt, würde ich die Formulierung so deuten, dass man sich mit den Händen den vom Sitzen an den Schenkeln haften gebliebenen Staub/Dreck abklopft.

Answer (score 0):

"Etwas hinter sich her ziehen". In diesem Fall schlägt die Umrissenheit um seine Schenkel.

Bespiel:

Mir schien, und ich glaubt es im Traum,
Glaubt es mit krampfendem Lachen: ein himmlischer Riese,
Irgend einer der Wandler da oben,
Die sich Wolkenfetzen um die Schenkel schlagen,
warf eine faulige Blutorange ins Meer;

(aus: Otto Julius Bierbaum: Irrgarten der Liebe. Berlin/Leipzig 1901, S. 258-260.)

Ogün